# Unwanted two-way data binding when passing data to Ember Octane component

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane

I'm following the Full Stack Ember with Rails course on [Embercasts](https://embercasts.com). As they don't use Octane yet, I change the code where necessary to work with Ember 3.22. I'm stuck in video 22 where I need to pass data to a component. This data should only be passed to the component, but when updating a value inside it, I don't want to see the change in other places.

In the video, this is taken care of in a `didReceiveAttrs()` handler, but this is not available in Octane. Instead, the Ember docs describe [one way data flow](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/glimmer-components/#toc_one-way-data-flow) as what happens automatically. In my case, it doesn't:

```
{{! author.edit.hbs !}}

<h3>Editing: {{model.last}},  {{model.first}}</h3>
<AuthorForm @author={{model}} />

{{! author-form.hbs !}}

<div class="field">
  <label for="first">First name</label>
  <Input @id="first" type="text" placeholder="First name" @value={{this.author.first}}/>
</div>  

<div class="field">
  <label for="last">Last name</label>
  <Input @id="last" type="text" placeholder="Last name" @value={{this.author.last}}/>
</div>
```

The `h3` updates whenever I change the value in one of the component's inputs. What's wrong here?

Comment: it works as expected if I remove '@' from the *value* attribute: `<Input type="text" value={{this.author.first}}/>` But according to [the docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/built-in-components/#toc_setting-attributes-on-input), only *@value* is correct.

Comment: How does the course deal with the data binding? If you don't want to propagate the change you'll need to change how you do things a bit to store the data somewhere else first and then to update the model when appropriate.

Comment: I don't really know how to answer your question. It's a complex one, and on the other hand not that important here as I have to modify the code to make it work with Octane anyway. I kept the `Input` component after all and used copied values inside `@value` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The `<Input>` component shipped with Ember.js uses two-way data binding for the value.

Arguments passed to a component are immutable. You can not change `this.args` nor a value passed with `@`. But object passed in as values of arguments are not frozen.

Taking this template as an example:

```
<Input @value={{@post.title}}/>
```

It will not mutate `@post` but the `title` property of the object passed in as `@post` argument.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I use this syntax (in my case <Input type="text" @value={{@author.first}}/>) and then add a few letters in the input field, these letters also appear in the `h3` which is outside the component.

Comment: This wasn't meant as a fix but only as an explanation what is going on.

Comment: I see. You wrote "used" in your first sentence, so I thought two-way data binding only applied to `Input` components in pre-Octane Ember. I guess I'll use a native `input` field instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for that confusion. Changed to uses.